# WPF Repeater (like) control for collection source?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF `DataGrid` bound to `ObservableCollection`. 
Each item in my collection has Property which is a `List<someObject>`. 
In my row details pane, I would like to write out formatted text blocks for each item in this collection. The end result would be something equivalent to:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource NBBOTextBlockStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
<TextBlock.Inlines>
    <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Exchanges[0].Name}" />
    <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Exchanges[0].Price}" />
    <LineBreak />
    <Run Foreground="LightGray" Text="{Binding Path=Exchanges[0].Quantity}" />
</TextBlock.Inlines>
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource NBBOTextBlockStyle}">
<TextBlock.Inlines>
    <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Exchanges[1].Name}" />
    <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Exchanges[1].Price}" />
    <LineBreak />
    <Run Foreground="LightGray" Text="{Binding Path=Exchanges[1].Quantity}" />
</TextBlock.Inlines>
</TextBlock>
```

and so on 0-n times.

I've tried using `ItemsControl` for this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Exchanges}">
    <DataTemplate>
        <Label>test</Label>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

however, this appears to be only meant for more static sources, as it throws the following exception (collection is not altered after creation):

> ItemsControl Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead*

Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: The ItemsControl should be fine. You usually get this error when using the Items property of the ItemsControl while your ItemsSource is bound, could that be the case?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

What you did by specifying `<DataTemplate .../>` inside of `ItemsControl` is you added this  instance of `DataTemplate` to default property of `ItemsControl` which is `Items`. So the exception you got is the expected result: first you specify the `ItemsSource`, then you modify `Items`. Instead you should modify `ItemTemplate` property on your `ItemsControl` like so:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Exchanges}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label>test</Label>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: awesome, thanks. anyway i can make the items in that template stack up horizontally instead of vertically?

Comment: Change the ItemsPanel to use an ItemsPanelTemplate with a StackPanel that has Orientation="Horizontal".

Comment: Edit: added sample `ItemPanelTemplate` suggested by John. You can use `WrapPanel` instead of `StackPanel`, if you want line wrapping.