# Databinding in wpf as that of repeater in asp.net

Tags: wpf

I am having a repeater like this in asp.net

```
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptrExperience" OnItemDataBound = "itembound">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="experience">
                               <a><asp:Label ID="Label13" class="accounts-link" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("JobTitle") %>'></asp:Label></a> <br />
                               <a> <asp:Label ID="Label14" class="accounts-link" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Company") %>'></asp:Label></a><br />
                                <%-- <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("town") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                                <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Location") %>'></asp:Label><br />--%>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Period") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                                <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Description") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                <a id="ae" href="#?w=750" class=" floatleft poplight"  rel="popup6" runat ="server"  >Endorse <asp:Label ID="en" runat="server" Text='<%#Name(Eval("UserId")) %>'></asp:Label>'s Work in <asp:Label ID="en1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Company") %>'></asp:Label></a>
                                <a  id="te" runat="server" rel="tooltip" title="You can endorse your collegue or friend you have worked together.This is your professional opinion so keep it professional.Tip: Keep it clear and simple, Your friend can delete your endorsementif they are innappropriate. "><img src="images/icon-tips.png" width="14" height="15" alt="tips" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
```

and binding data using linq

I want the same to displayed in a  wpf application. I am new to wpf can any one help me out

Comment: Was asked before [WPF Repeater (like) control for collection source?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010131/wpf-repeater-like-control-for-collection-source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `ItemsControl` will probably fit your need:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ...}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- Template goes here ... -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```