# Populate textbox values based on a list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have about 50 different pieces of data that I need to call, for minimum and maximum values. I'm sure there's a better way than doing the following:

```
 public void refreshminmaxvalues(List<minmaxvalues> listminmaxvalues)
    {
        txtMinA_1.Text = minmaxvalueslist[0].minvalue.ToString();
        txtMaxA_1.Text = minmaxvalueslist[0].maxvalue.ToString();
        txtMinB_1.Text = minmaxvalueslist[0].minvalueB.ToString();
        txtMaxB_1.Text = minmaxvalueslist[0].maxvalueB.ToString();
        txtMin_2.Text = minmaxvalueslist[1].minvalue.ToString();
        txtMax_2.Text = minmaxvalueslist[1].maxvalue.ToString();

    }
```

The above code takes values from a list for min and max. The `MinA` and `MinB` are two values that are linked together, and thus will be called differently from the rest. Everything past `txtMax_2` will just have one min and one max value.

Does anyone know a better, more "efficient" way of doing this code, rather than just writing out all 50+ values?

If it helps, these are the values that are edited in XAML:

```
          <!-- Minimum -->
        <TextBox Name="txtMinA_1" Text=""/>
        <TextBox Name="txtMinB_1" Text=""/>
        <TextBox Name="txtMin_2" Text=""/>
        <TextBox Name="txtMin_3" Text=""/>
        <TextBox Name="txtMin_4" Text=""/>

         <!-- Maximum -->
        <TextBox Name="txtMaxA_1" Text=""/>
        <TextBox Name="txtMaxB_1" Text=""/>
        <TextBox Name="txtMax_2" Text=""/>
        <TextBox Name="txtMax_3" Text=""/>
        <TextBox Name="txtMaxH_4" Text=""/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use an ItemsControl and bind to that:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Mins">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding minvalue}"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding minvalueB}"></TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
<ItemsControl x:Name="Maxes">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding maxvalue}"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding maxvalueB}"></TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

You could bind a type to it like so:

```
Mins.ItemsSource = listminmaxvalues;
Maxes.ItemsSource = listminmaxvalues;
```

More info: [WPF Repeater (like) control for collection source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010131/wpf-repeater-like-control-for-collection-source)

Comment: I like your answer better than mine however the OP needs to know what databinding is

Comment: which he should if he's going to develop in WPF, but that's a bit out of scope for this question.

Comment: I don't think it is. Both of our answer use databinding where in his original question he isn't at all. If he implements your answer it won't work. It's not a complete solution.

Comment: Since i'm setting the `ItemsSource` directly in the codebehind instead of doing it with a view model as a parent DataContext, this should be a complete solution.

Comment: I'm aware of data binding, but I'd find it hard to implement in an easy format along with the code I'm running. I have also written it out, for all the values I'm using, and I think I've found an error with the first answer, but I'll dig a bit more and report back

Comment: @Badja if it's hard for you to add databinding with the code that you're writing then you need to re-evaluate your architecture. I write EXTREMELY complex WPF applications and the more complex they get, the better Databinding works.

Comment: @Badja this question is exactly why you should use databinding- what would take you 50 lines of error-prone code (due to copy and pasting) can be done in far fewer.

Answer (score 1):

If you know exactly how many pieces of data are being returned then you should use models and databinding instead.

For example:

YourXaml.xaml

EDIT: use the ItemsTemplateSelector in DLeh's answer but the other stuff in mine still makes sense and is relavent.

```
 <TextBox Name="txtMinA_1" Text="{Binding txtMinA_1.minvalue"/>
 <TextBox Name="txtMinA_1" Text="{Binding txtMinB_1.maxvalue"/>
 ect...
```

YourXaml.xaml.cs

```
public class YourXaml{
     public YourXaml(){
        this.DataContext = new YourViewModel();
     }
}
```

YourViewModel.cs

```
public YourViewModel{
    private minmaxvalues _txtMinA_1;
    private minmaxvalues _txtMinB_1;

    public minmaxvalues txtMinA_1
    { 
       get{ return _txtMinA_1; }
       set{ _txtMinA_1 = value; }
    }
    public minmaxvalues txtMinB_1
    { 
       get{ return _txtMinB_1; }
       set{ _txtMinB_1= value; }
    }

}
```

By using this structure you are decoupling your view (YourXaml.xaml) from your data which is in the models and viewmodel. It's a much more efficient and industry accepted way of working in WPF.

[To learn more about MVVM go here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)  You are going to want to learn this along with what DataBinding is.