# List of objects and ComboBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, binding

Here's my problem:
I've got these classes:

```
public class CsvField
{
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public CsvField(string content)
    {
        Content = content;
    }

}

public class CsvLine
{
    public List<CsvField> Fields = new List<CsvField>();

    public int LineNumber;

}

public static class Settings
{
    public static List<string> Tags = new List<string>();
    public static CsvLine AllHeaders = new CsvLine();
}
```

What I want to do, is display the ListBox containing every member of Settings.AllHeaders.Fields and a ComboBox containing all members of Settings.Tags list (placed horizontally - a member of AllHeaders on the left and a ComboBox next to it). So if I had 4 headers, I would get a List of those 4 headers and 4 ComboBoxes, each of them next to individual header. Each of these ComboBoxes would contain a list of tags.

So, I defined a DataTemplate:

```
<Window x:Class="CSV_To_Tags_App.Window2"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:CSV_To_Tags_App"
        Title="Window2" Height="435" Width="566">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type loc:CsvField}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock x:Name="HeaderTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding Content}"
                />
                <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>                      
    </Window.Resources>


    <Grid>

        <Label Content="Available headers" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="HeadersListtListBox"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                 Height="254" Margin="36,104,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="452"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>       
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now, XAML code above is incomplete, because I don't know how to:
1. Bind TextBlock to Settings.AllHeaders.Fields.Content
2. Bind ComboBox to Tags List

Comment: Use repeater http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010131/wpf-repeater-like-control-for-collection-source

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand how that example could help me.

Answer (score 0):

The link provided by @MD's does provide the solution to what you are asking in your question, but you have to rearrange things a little bit to see it.
The XAML below will give you what you are asking for, assuming your class that you are binding to is set up properly for data binding (implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface).  There are lots of examples on this site of how to properly implement that portion.

```
<Window x:Class="CSV_To_Tags_App.Window2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:CSV_To_Tags_App"
    Title="Window2" Height="435" Width="566">
 <Grid>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Settings.AllHeadings.Fields}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Content}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Settings}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tags}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
  </StackPanel>
 </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: But what if my Settings class is static? I can't implement interfaces to it.

Comment: And do I really need that INotifyChanged interface? I just want to display data without an option to modify it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that your Settings class was static.  You can't do data binding to that.  Data binding requires that you have an object to bind to, meaning an instantiated object, which is the exact opposite of a static class.  On your other note: INotifyPropertyChanged is not for the purpose of modifying your data from the UI, it is used to display the bound data in the UI.  You can do a limited form of data binding without it, but any changes to the bound objects in code (which is what you are doing) will not show in the UI without implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.