# wpf repeater like items control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

I have a wpf application where I want repeater like functionality. I am referring to the following post [Wpf repeater like control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010131/wpf-repeater-like-control-for-collection-source) So I have list that is like the items source for the ItemsControl. What I am trying to display is something as follows;

> Parent Content1
>         Child content1.
>
> Parent Content2
>           Child content2.
>
> So on....

So the Parent Content 1 and Parent Content 2 are names property inside the Data object and Child content1 and Child Content2 are like value property inside the data object.

Here is the sample app I created but I get a xaml parse exception saying "'Add value to collection of type 'System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection' threw an exception". This is just partial xaml. I am new to the items control. Please help.

```
 <ItemsControl
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllItems}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding names}"></Label>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
                        <TextBlock
                            Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Mainwindow.cs

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            public List<Data> AllItems { get; set; }
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.DataContext = this;
                Populate();
            }

        public void Populate()
        {
        AllItems = new List<Data>();
        Data data = new Data();
        data.names = "Parent Content1";
        data.value = "Child Content1";
        AllItems.Add(data);
        Data data1 = new Data();
        data1.names = "Parent Content2";
        data1.value = "Child Content2";
        AllItems.Add(data1);
       }        
        }
        public class Data
        {
            public string names { get; set; }
            public string value { get; set; }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to set the `ItemsPanelTemplate`, as it uses a `StackPanel` by default. The issue here is because you are also adding a `TextBlock` inside the `ItemsPanelTemplate`. Remove it, then add the correct data formatting in the `ItemTemplate`.

```
<ItemsControl
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding names}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding value}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```